# How can I remove duplicates out of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayP.size(); i++) {

        if (arrayP.get(i) == What to put here?) {
              arrayP.remove(i)
        }
}
```

If I put `i+1` it just compares side by side. How can I get it to run through each element?

Element 1 then run through the whole ArrayList. Then element 2 run through ArrayList.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That question is simply about *detecting* whether duplicates are present, not about removing them.

Comment: [ArrayList#removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

```
list = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(list));
```

If the order of elements does not matter, you should use a normal [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead. In fact, if it's logical to do so, you might consider using a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in the first place. Read about the differences between the two and pick the structure that's more appropriate.

Comment: +1. Not only removed duplicates, but also **preserved** the initial order of elements in list.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Set arrayPSet = new LinkedHashSet(arrayP);
```

now arrayPSet holds your array removing it's duplicate values, then you can use it, you can 
re-assign your list to this set once again, like

```
arrayP = new ArrayList(arrayPSet);
```

now duplicates are removes

just make sure to override the equals() and hashCode() methods if arrayP list holds objects created by you

ok, i updated it maybe this works, i didnt try the order issue, but there are TreeSet/Comparators/Comparables solutions , just try this modification first

Comment: Fail. Changes the order of the elements of the ArrayList.

Comment: @StephenC:  I don't see how that's a hard and fast requirement, per se...